# DNS TXT record returns a CNAME

Tags: domain-name-system

I want to update a letsencrypt certificate for a wildcart sub-subdomain. For that I created in my zone file a TXT entry

```
_acme-challenge.dep       IN TXT     "<...challenge...>"
```

This subdomain also has an own A name

```
dep                     IN A       <external ip>
```

And a CNAME

```
*.dep                    IN CNAME    dep
```

I already deleted that CNAME but `dig -t txt _acme-challenge.dep.mydomain` still returns the CNAME and not the TXT with the challenge.

```
;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 512
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;_acme-challenge.dep.mydomain. IN TXT

;; ANSWER SECTION:
_acme-challenge.dep.mydomain. 6092 IN CNAME dep.mydomain.
```

Why is the TXT request returning a CNAME and how can I get the DNS to understand, that for acme-challenge it supposed to return the challenge?

EDIT: I ran certbot-auto anyways and it completed the challenge successfully (obviously it's smarter than me)... now I am wondering what I did wrong checking with dig the TXT entry since I always got CNAME and not TXT return.

Comment: Are you sure that dig was pointing at your DNS server and not something that had cached the earlier version?

Comment: I tried it with dig -f txt url 8.8.8.8 and 1.1.1.1 too. Not sure if I can force dig to bypass any caches.

Comment: You need to query your authoritative nameserver, see dig `@` option.

Comment: You do not need to remove the wildcard: per DNS specifications the wildcard only comes into play if no direct relevant record is found. So it can coexist with other records.